# Ayuda para detener e iniciar temporizador

Tags: javascript, html5

tengo el siguiente código de JavaScript en el cual coloque un temporizador que se inicia al cargar la página, pero quiero que se detenga si se agota el tiempo y vuelva a iniciar cuando de al botón de "Jugar de nuevo" ya sea que haya perdido o ganado, espero alguien pueda ayudarme a solucionarlo en que debo agregar o en que estoy mal.

Soy algo nuevo en esto de JavaScript y aunque estuve agregando las funciones de comenzar y finalizar temporizador, no me dieron resultado. Solo deje el código que es funcional hasta el momento.

Código JavaScript:

```js
var segundosInicio = 30;


window.onload = tiempo;

function tiempo() {

    document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = segundosInicio;
    if (segundosInicio == 0) {
        console.log('Final');

        Swal.fire({
            title: "¡Se te acabó el tiempo!",
            html: `<img class="img-fluid" src="../img/perdiste1.png" alt="Ganaste">`,
            confirmButtonText: "Jugar de nuevo",
        })
        for (var j = 0; j < piezas.length; j++) {
            piezas[j].setAttribute("x", Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1));
            piezas[j].setAttribute("y", Math.floor((Math.random() * 409) + 1));
            piezas[i].setAttribute("onmousedown", "seleccionarElemento(evt)");
        }
    } else {
        segundosInicio -= 1;
        var ejecutar = setTimeout("tiempo()", 1000);
    }
}


var piezas = document.getElementsByClassName('movil');

var tamWidh = [134, 192, 134, 163, 134, 163, 134, 192, 134];
var tamHeight = [163, 134, 163, 134, 192, 134, 163, 134, 163];


for (var i = 0; i < piezas.length; i++) {
    piezas[i].setAttribute("width", tamWidh[i]);
    piezas[i].setAttribute("height", tamHeight[i]);
    piezas[i].setAttribute("x", Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1));
    piezas[i].setAttribute("y", Math.floor((Math.random() * 409) + 1));
    piezas[i].setAttribute("onmousedown", "seleccionarElemento(evt)");
}

var elementSelect = 0;
var currentX = 0;
var currentY = 0;
var currentPosX = 0;
var currentPosY = 0;

function seleccionarElemento(evt) {
    elementSelect = reordenar(evt);
    currentX = evt.clientX;
    currentY = evt.clientY;
    currentPosx = parseFloat(elementSelect.getAttribute("x"));
    currentPosy = parseFloat(elementSelect.getAttribute("y"));
    elementSelect.setAttribute("onmousemove", "moverElemento(evt)");
}

function moverElemento(evt) {
    var dx = evt.clientX - currentX;
    var dy = evt.clientY - currentY;
    currentPosx = currentPosx + dx;
    currentPosy = currentPosy + dy;
    elementSelect.setAttribute("x", currentPosx);
    elementSelect.setAttribute("y", currentPosy);
    currentX = evt.clientX;
    currentY = evt.clientY;
    elementSelect.setAttribute("onmouseout", "deseleccionarElemento(evt)");
    elementSelect.setAttribute("onmouseup", "deseleccionarElemento(evt)");
    iman();
}

function deseleccionarElemento(evt) {
    testing();
    if (elementSelect != 0) {
        elementSelect.removeAttribute("onmousemove");
        elementSelect.removeAttribute("onmouseout");
        elementSelect.removeAttribute("onmouseup");
        elementSelect = 0;
    }
}

var entorno = document.getElementById('entorno');

function reordenar(evt) {
    var padre = evt.target.parentNode;
    var clone = padre.cloneNode(true);
    var id = padre.getAttribute("id");
    entorno.removeChild(document.getElementById(id));
    entorno.appendChild(clone);
    return entorno.lastChild.firstChild;
}

var origX = [200, 304, 466, 200, 333, 437, 200, 304, 466];
var origY = [100, 100, 100, 233, 204, 233, 337, 366, 337];

function iman() {
    for (var i = 0; i < piezas.length; i++) {
        if (Math.abs(currentPosx - origX[i]) < 15 && Math.abs(currentPosy - origY[i]) < 15) {
            elementSelect.setAttribute("x", origX[i]);
            elementSelect.setAttribute("y", origY[i]);
        }
    }
}


var win = document.getElementById("win");

function testing() {
    var bien_ubicada = 0;
    var padres = document.getElementsByClassName('padre');
    for (var i = 0; i < piezas.length; i++) {
        var posx = parseFloat(padres[i].firstChild.getAttribute("x"));
        var posy = parseFloat(padres[i].firstChild.getAttribute("y"));
        ide = padres[i].getAttribute("id");
        if (origX[ide] == posx && origY[ide] == posy) {
            bien_ubicada = bien_ubicada + 1;
            if (origX[ide] == posx && origY[ide] == posy) {


            }
        }
    }

    if (bien_ubicada == 9) {
        win.play();
        Swal.fire({
            title: "¡Grandioso. Has ganado!",
            html: `<img class="img-fluid" src="../img/premio.png" alt="Ganaste">`,
            confirmButtonText: "Jugar de nuevo",
        })
        for (var i = 0; i < piezas.length; i++) {
            piezas[i].setAttribute("x", Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1));
            piezas[i].setAttribute("y", Math.floor((Math.random() * 409) + 1));
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agrego un código que implementa la lógica: se detiene cuando el tiempo termina y se reinicia al presionar un botón:

```js
const tiempoTotal = 5;
var   tiempoActual = tiempoTotal;
var timeout;


var ele = document.getElementById("countdown");


function tiempo(){

  if(tiempoActual == 0) {
    mostrarDialogo();
  }
  else {
    tiempoActual--;
    ele.innerHTML = tiempoActual;
    setTimeout(()=> tiempo(),1000);
  }
}


// iniciar el temporizador cuando carga la página
tiempo();


function reiniciarTemporizador(){
  tiempoActual = tiempoTotal;
  tiempo();
}

function mostrarDialogo(){

   Swal.fire({
            title: "¡Se te acabó el tiempo!",
            icon: "info",
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonText: 'Jugar de nuevo',
            cancelButtonText: 'cancelar'
        }
    ).then((result) => {
          if (result.value) {
             reiniciarTemporizador();
          }
     })
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@9"></script>
</head>
<body>

<label id="countdown"></label>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Tu código me esta ayudando, pero en el que yo tengo desde el mismo JavaScript me manda una ventana en la que presiono un botón y no esta incluido en el HTML como lo hiciste tu. La pregunta ahora es: ¿Cómo puedo cambiar ese botón "reiniciar" del HTML al JavaScript en la parte de "Swal.fire" donde esta "confirmButtonText: "Jugar de nuevo","?

Comment: Modifiqué el ejemplo para incluir la demo con Swal.

Answer (score 2):

Sweet Alert te permite usar [promesas](https://sweetalert.js.org/guides/#using-promises) y devuelve verdadero solo cuando se hace clic en el botón, por lo que solo debes analizar el valor devuelto para saber qué hacer:

```
    Swal.fire({
        title: "¡Se te acabó el tiempo!",
        html: `<img class="img-fluid" src="../img/perdiste1.png" alt="Ganaste">`,
        confirmButtonText: "Jugar de nuevo",
    }).then(value => {
        if(!value) {
            // El clic no fue en el botón confirmar
            // Fin del juego
            return;
        }
        // Volver a empezar, supongo que esto es parte de la configuración de inicio            
        for (var j = 0; j < piezas.length; j++) {
            piezas[j].setAttribute("x", Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1));
            piezas[j].setAttribute("y", Math.floor((Math.random() * 409) + 1));
            piezas[i].setAttribute("onmousedown", "seleccionarElemento(evt)");
        }
        // Reiniciar temporizador
        segundosInicio = 30;
        // ¡A jugar!
        setTimeout("tiempo()", 1000);
     });
```